# php Guessing game

Tags: php, html, session

l write a  guessing game by php  but i have a problem

i need when the user try more than 3 time tell him in another page he lose 
i create a session and put a count , the counter increment while the user submit   but the counter does not increment 
code :

```
<?php 

session_start();   

$_SESSION['count'] = 0 ;
 ?> 


<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="game.php"> 
<input type="hidden" name="Guessingnumber" value=25>
Enter a number <input type="number" name="num">  <br> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Guess">
</form> 

</body>
</html> 

<?php

$GuessingNumber = $_GET['Guessingnumber'] ; 
$UserNumber = $_GET['num'] ;   


 if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {  



 if ($GuessingNumber > $UserNumber) {

    echo("the number you Enter is smaller than GuessingNumber")  ; 

    $_SESSION['count'] ++ ; 


  } 

   elseif ($GuessingNumber < $UserNumber) {

    echo("the number you Enter is bigger than GuessingNumber") ; 

    $_SESSION['count'] ++ ;


  } 

  else {

    echo "you are won";  

    $_SESSION['count'] ++ ; 


  }

 } 



 ?>
```

Comment: everytime you start the file, you reset the counter to 0. make it dependant on if the counter is set or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form submits to the same page, so all the code on in that script will run. So each time the form is submitted the following is ran:

```
$_SESSION['count'] = 0 ;
```

So essentially everytime the user makes a guess the counter will be set to 0, so the counter never really becomes greater than 1 as it keeps getting reset to 0 on the submission of the form (a guess)

:)

Answer (score 1):

Each time the user submits their game, the very first lines of your PHP run.

```
session_start();   

$_SESSION['count'] = 0 ;
```

That means that each time you try to make the score bigger, you first reset it to 0, and then make it bigger by 1.

That means you can never get a score larger than 1.

To solve the issue, you should check if `$_SESSION["count"]` has already been set, and if it has, not reset it back to 0.

Additionally, you should reset it when it gets to 3.